# Distance from a closed subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let the Banach space $E= (C[0,1], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ the space of continuous functions on [0,1] with the supremum norm. Define
$$A=\Big\{u\in E:~ u(0)=0,\quad \int_0^1 u(t)d t\geq1\Big\}.$$

Then compute $d_A(0)=\inf\{\|u\|_\infty:~~u\in A\}.$

Since for all $u\in A$ we have $$1\leq \int_0^1 u(t) dt\leq \|u\|_\infty.$$

My guess is that $d_A(0)=1$.

But I cannot find sequence $(u_n)\subset A$ such that $\|u_n\|_\infty\to 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $u_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows. Set $u_n(0)=0$, $u_n(t)=c_n$ (where $c_n$ is a constant that we will specify later) for all $t\in[1/n,1]$ and extend linearly in the interval $[0,1/n]$.

Then $$\int_0^1u_n(t)dt=\frac{c_n}{2n}+c_n(1-\frac{1}{n})=\frac{2c_n(n-1)+c_n}{2n}=c_n\cdot\frac{2n-1}{2n}$$

We specify $c_n:=\frac{2n}{2n-1}$. Thus $\int_0^1u_n(t)dt=1$ for all $n$. On the other hand, it is evident that $\|u_n\|_\infty=c_n$ and it is directly seen that $c_n\to1^+$.